# SQL Total sales and contacts by state

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query that will return the total number of contacts and the total number of sales made in each state.  This is as close as I have been able to get, but is returning 31 total sales when only 26 were made, and 737 contacts when 694 were made.  Also if possible I would like for it to display one row for each state with total # of sales and contacts in that state displaying in the row.  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT LD.STABBR AS STATE,  
ISNULL (count(case when cl.disposition = '750254B1-7DF4-4677-90D5-F2CF8FB3FAD3' then cl.disposition end),0) AS SALES,
count(cl.disposition) as contacts

FROM CLIENTS.DBO.nptLead_81140201650614 LD
inner JOIN
ASDM.DBO.CALLLOG CL ON LD.ACCTNO = CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE CL.START > '2015-10-08' AND CL.START < '2015-10-09' AND
cl.disposition IN (

            'A582678D-365B-4ADF-9C61-71718872F162',
                  --TURNDOWN
            '8B54C708-320E-403F-B80B-4FFA9AB4F240',
                  --TURNDOWN HNGUP_IMMED
            '375AF837-A09B-4600-A885-ACF2C7ED8FB9',
                  --TURNDOWN SND_FND_ELSW
            'B643C325-F08D-4811-BA57-30841F46D47F',
                  --TURNDOWN GAVE LOCAL
            'C8A236A8-0470-41CC-B54E-6E42778479E8',
                  --TURNDOWN TIMING
            '7877D7E7-719B-42AF-8ED2-9B0042E10BC3',
                  --TURNDOWN ALREADY HELPED
            'DF1CD1EF-3282-44AA-AF9D-FE0367CFA056',
                  --TURNDOWN TOO MANY CALLS
            '6F9CD16A-40DE-4786-841F-36E607FE6184',
                  --TURNDOWN CAN'T AFFORD
            '0EE86647-8AEB-41F1-A810-4077ACB79F44',
                  --TURNDOWN NOT INTERESTED
            'CFAAC025-BD19-4B28-BCBF-4D9EA65874D3',
                  --TURNDOWN NOT CMT OVR PHN       
            'E77FB052-5029-467C-9CE8-19D1D2EEE62C',
                  --TURNDOWN ON DNC LIST
            'D3B62778-B76A-47F2-8E1E-AA982990E5C8',
                  --TURNDOWN OTHER
            'FAB27564-0C34-4D99-897F-BC03C09B9F81',
                  --SALE VERIFIED
            '750254B1-7DF4-4677-90D5-F2CF8FB3FAD3',
                  --SALE UNVERIFIED
            '14BE3DFE-CF5C-4242-B19D-D424AEA0FCC8',
                  --DECEASED
            '0A513C75-2272-40BA-96CA-32305D122E41',
                  --DONATION
            'B2C3EB3F-D961-4D18-954F-BB24DDA597A2',
                  --DONATION UNVERIFIED
            'DDF1DF59-5C7A-4952-A5F4-925C4BCADA10',
                  --ZB
            '1545280C-B33F-4C24-9108-3979F7BD2B32',
                  --DNC
            '92B96771-95F7-46D2-8B42-010EB2D8A329')
                  --AUTO DNC
    GROUP BY LD.STABBR WITH ROLLUP


    ORDER BY LD.STABBR
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d849c/7/0

I want the results to come out like

```
state   contacts  sales
ga         2       1
fl         1       0
total      3       1
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO, please in order to us help you, you must help us first. To do what you need without knowing your tables structure is almost impossible. So add a data sample (no need to be real just columns equivalent) and the desired result FROM that sample you gave. It would be even better if you can provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with it. Think with us here, if you read a question without knowing about it would you be able to answer!? ;)

Comment: @JorgeCampos TL;DR, but +1 after spotting *SQLFiddle* and *desired results*.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu would you mind to explain what is "TL;DR" just curious, english is not my first language and I don't know most of these short words :) Thanks in advance! I've learned what ASAP means a little time ago :P

Comment: Too Long ; Didn't Read.

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle with a small data sample.  Also TL;DR is commonly use  on the internet.  In this context I think he meant he just skimmed your response to my question as opposed to actually reading it, and it looked like you were on the right track in asking me for sqlfiddle and desired results.

Comment: Thank you both! New knowlegde is always welcome... :)

Comment: Also your sqlfiddle link is broken, can you check it?

Comment: When you're getting more results than expected it probably means the join condition is wrong.

Comment: Without seeing your tables, I can't be sure, but I would guess that your extra rows are a result of multiple calls to the same accounts/customers.  (Since you're joining to that table only by Account/Customer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your global problem, but the problem with your SqlFiddle is pretty simple, just replace

```
WHERE CL.START > '2015-10-08' AND CL.START < '2015-10-09' AND
```

with

```
WHERE CL.START > '2015-10-08' AND CL.START <= '2015-10-09' AND
```

Since you're dealing with `Date`, and not `Datetime`, there is no value between 9 and 8.

---

EDIT : Also, to add the "total" label, you can use the grouping function by replacing

```
select stabbr as state
```

with

```
select CASE WHEN GROUPING(stabbr) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE stabbr END as state,
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Well, yes... but now we cannot trace your problem anymore since you provided a working SQLfiddle to display what should be an error. Unless you provide some faulty data, we cannot help you find the fault.

Comment: Yes, this is leading me to believe that's there may be a problem with the data.